# Evaluating the integral $\int_A y e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}d(x, y)$ where $A$ is a certain set

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

I first want to justify why the set $A = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x < y, y > 0\}$ is Borel-measurable, and then calculate the integral

$$\int_A y e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}d(x, y)$$

I think the first part is the easier one: $A$ is open, hence Borel-measurable.

I don't exactly know how I can evaluate the integral though. Can I simply first integrate with respect to $x$, then again with respect to $y$ (or vice versa)? Even if I can, it's still irritating me on how to deal with this set $A$ that I'm integrating over. How would I handle this set?

Comment: u might draw a picture of ur integration region and observe that symmetry yields an awesome simplification here.

Comment: @tired could you maybe go a little more into detail? I draw $A$, but somehow, I'm not seeing yet how that helps me simplify the integral.

Comment: the area of integration is a triangle in which is half the first quadrant right? so what happens if u compare this with an integration over the whole first quadrant?

Comment: Does that mean that the integral over the triangle is half of the value of the integral over the quadrant? But why would that be so? I'm sorry but I cannot quite follow yet. I also noticed that the function is even with respect to $x$ and odd with respect to $y$; so since $A$ also contains the (entire) 2nd quadrant, $A$ can be decomposed into the 2nd quadrant and the "triangle" in the 1st quadrant, and the function integrated over the 1st quadrant is the same as integrated over the 2nd quadrant. But somehow I still fail to see how that makes it easier to figure out the value of the triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_A y e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}d(x, y) = \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\int_0^xye^{-y^2/2} dy\;dx$$

From there a simple substitution and evaluation of the inner integral reduces to a sum of known integrals.